# How to stop truncating trailing 0 from TextWriter?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code

```
 private const string STANDARD_6DIGIT_FORMAT = "{0:0.0#####}~";
    private const string STANDARD_5DIGIT_FORMAT = "{0:0.0####}~";
    private const string STANDARD_4DIGIT_FORMAT = "{0:0.0###}~";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("d:\\textwriter.txt");

        writeFile.Write(STANDARD_5DIGIT_FORMAT, 0.600000);
        writeFile.Flush();
        writeFile.Close();
        writeFile = null;

    }
```

When I am trying to format 0.600000 to 0.60000 in a txt file, it truncates the trailing zeroes.

Can someone help me to stop this ? I want to retain all those values in txt file

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: They must be knowing some logic to do that probably. it is not about TextWriter, it is about stopping trailing 0 from truncating

Comment: OK, wasn't obvious from your C# example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried converting floating number to string using `0` instead of `#` and then writing it to the file

```
//Use '0' instead of '#'
private const string STANDARD_5DIGIT_FORMAT = "{0:0.000000}~";

...

writeFile.Write(0.600000.ToString(STANDARD_5DIGIT_FORMAT));

....
```

From documentation,

[Format specifier:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

> `#`: Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, **no digit appears** in the result string.

> `0`: Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, **zero appears** in the result string.

In your case, you need to use `0` instead of `#` to replace zero as formatted value

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L5PyQZ)

Comment: It gives out {0:0.6}~  When I wrote                 writeFile.Write(0.600000.ToString(STANDARD_5DIGIT_FORMAT));

Comment: Can use we use 0 instead of # even it is possible that the values might be non zero as well?

Comment: Yes,`Console.WriteLine(0.610000.ToString("0.000000"));` will print `0.610000`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this fits your project but I had similar problem converting decimal values to EUR currency.
You can make just .ToString("F6");

```
writeFile.Write((0.6).ToString("F6"));
```

comma and dot's problem:

```
        var cultureFranch = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", false);
        var nfi = cultureFranch.NumberFormat;
        nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
        nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

        writeFile.Write((0.6).ToString("F6", nfi));
```